# got a compiling error while programming node mcu

Tags: arduino-iot-cloud

i was programming my node mcu i modified the code and got a complination error but when i compiled the original code i got no error
modified code

```
#include "arduino_secrets.h"
#include "thingProperties.h"

// define the GPIO connected with Relays and switches
#define RelayPin1 5  //D1
#define RelayPin2 4  //D2
#define RelayPin3 14 //D5
#define RelayPin4 12 //D6

#define RelayPin5 2  //d4
#define RelayPin6 0   //D3 
#define RelayPin7 13  //D7
#define RelayPin8 15   //d8

#define wifiLed   16   //D0

int toggleState_1 = 0; //Define integer to remember the toggle state for relay 1
int toggleState_2 = 0; //Define integer to remember the toggle state for relay 2
int toggleState_3 = 0; //Define integer to remember the toggle state for relay 3
int toggleState_4 = 0; //Define integer to remember the toggle state for relay 4
int toggleState_5 = 0; //Define integer to remember the toggle state for relay 5
int toggleState_6 = 0; //Define integer to remember the toggle state for relay 6
int toggleState_7 = 0; //Define integer to remember the toggle state for relay 7
int toggleState_8 = 0; //Define integer to remember the toggle state for relay 8

void relayOnOff(int relay) {

  switch (relay) {
    case 1:
      if (toggleState_1 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin1, HIGH); // turn on relay 1
        toggleState_1 = 1;
        Serial.println("Device1 ON");
      }
      else {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin1, LOW); // turn off relay 1
        toggleState_1 = 0;
        Serial.println("Device1 OFF");
      }
      delay(100);
      break;
    case 2:
      if (toggleState_2 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin2, HIGH); // turn on relay 2
        toggleState_2 = 1;
        Serial.println("Device2 ON");
      }
      else {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin2, LOW); // turn off relay 2
        toggleState_2 = 0;
        Serial.println("Device2 OFF");
      }
      delay(100);
      break;
    case 3:
      if (toggleState_3 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin3, HIGH); // turn on relay 3
        toggleState_3 = 1;
        Serial.println("Device3 ON");
      } else {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin3, LOW); // turn off relay 3
        toggleState_3 = 0;
        Serial.println("Device3 OFF");
      }
      delay(100);
      break;
     case 4:
      if (toggleState_4 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin4, HIGH); // turn on relay 3
        toggleState_4 = 1;
        Serial.println("Device4 ON");
      } else {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin4, LOW); // turn off relay 3
        toggleState_4 = 0;
        Serial.println("Device4 OFF");
      }
      delay(100);
      break;
     case 5:
      if (toggleState_5 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin5, HIGH); // turn on relay 3
        toggleState_5 = 1;
        Serial.println("Device5 ON");
      } else {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin5, LOW); // turn off relay 3
        toggleState_5 = 0;
        Serial.println("Device5 OFF");
      }
      delay(100);
      break;
     case 6:
      if (toggleState_6 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin6, HIGH); // turn on relay 3
        toggleState_6 = 1;
        Serial.println("Device6 ON");
      } else {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin6, LOW); // turn off relay 3
        toggleState_6 = 0;
        Serial.println("Device6 OFF");
      }
      delay(100);
      break;
     case 7:
      if (toggleState_7 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin7, HIGH); // turn on relay 3
        toggleState_7 = 1;
        Serial.println("Device7 ON");
      } else {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin7, LOW); // turn off relay 3
        toggleState_7 = 0;
        Serial.println("Device7 OFF");
      }
      delay(100);
      break;
    case 8:
      if (toggleState_8 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin8, HIGH); // turn on relay 4
        toggleState_8 = 1;
        Serial.println("Device8 ON");
      }
      else {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin8, LOW); // turn off relay 4
        toggleState_8 = 0;
        Serial.println("Device8 OFF");
      }
      delay(100);
      break;
    default : break;
  }
}

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // This delay gives the chance to wait for a Serial Monitor without blocking if none is found
  delay(1500);

  // Defined in thingProperties.h
  initProperties();

  // Connect to Arduino IoT Cloud
  ArduinoCloud.begin(ArduinoIoTPreferredConnection);

  setDebugMessageLevel(2);
  ArduinoCloud.printDebugInfo();

  pinMode(RelayPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RelayPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RelayPin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RelayPin4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RelayPin5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RelayPin6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RelayPin7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RelayPin8, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(wifiLed, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(RelayPin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RelayPin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RelayPin3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RelayPin4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RelayPin5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RelayPin6, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RelayPin7, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RelayPin8, LOW);

  digitalWrite(wifiLed, HIGH);  //Turn ON WiFi LED
}

void loop() {
  ArduinoCloud.update();
  

  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    digitalWrite(wifiLed, HIGH); //Turn ON WiFi LED
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(wifiLed, LOW); //Turn OFF WiFi LED
  }
}
```

the original code

```
#include "arduino_secrets.h"
#include "thingProperties.h"

// define the GPIO connected with Relays and switches
#define RelayPin1 5  //D1
#define RelayPin2 4  //D2
#define RelayPin3 14 //D5
#define RelayPin4 12 //D6

#define SwitchPin1 10  //SD3
#define SwitchPin2 0   //D3 
#define SwitchPin3 13  //D7
#define SwitchPin4 3   //RX

#define wifiLed   16   //D0

int toggleState_1 = 0; //Define integer to remember the toggle state for relay 1
int toggleState_2 = 0; //Define integer to remember the toggle state for relay 2
int toggleState_3 = 0; //Define integer to remember the toggle state for relay 3
int toggleState_4 = 0; //Define integer to remember the toggle state for relay 4

void relayOnOff(int relay) {

  switch (relay) {
    case 1:
      if (toggleState_1 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin1, HIGH); // turn on relay 1
        toggleState_1 = 1;
        Serial.println("Device1 ON");
      }
      else {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin1, LOW); // turn off relay 1
        toggleState_1 = 0;
        Serial.println("Device1 OFF");
      }
      delay(100);
      break;
    case 2:
      if (toggleState_2 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin2, HIGH); // turn on relay 2
        toggleState_2 = 1;
        Serial.println("Device2 ON");
      }
      else {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin2, LOW); // turn off relay 2
        toggleState_2 = 0;
        Serial.println("Device2 OFF");
      }
      delay(100);
      break;
    case 3:
      if (toggleState_3 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin3, HIGH); // turn on relay 3
        toggleState_3 = 1;
        Serial.println("Device3 ON");
      } else {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin3, LOW); // turn off relay 3
        toggleState_3 = 0;
        Serial.println("Device3 OFF");
      }
      delay(100);
      break;
    case 4:
      if (toggleState_4 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin4, HIGH); // turn on relay 4
        toggleState_4 = 1;
        Serial.println("Device4 ON");
      }
      else {
        digitalWrite(RelayPin4, LOW); // turn off relay 4
        toggleState_4 = 0;
        Serial.println("Device4 OFF");
      }
      delay(100);
      break;
    default : break;
  }
}

void manual_control() {
  //Manual Switch Control
  if (digitalRead(SwitchPin1) == LOW) {
    delay(200);
    relayOnOff(1);
  }
  else if (digitalRead(SwitchPin2) == LOW) {
    delay(200);
    relayOnOff(2);
  }
  else if (digitalRead(SwitchPin3) == LOW) {
    delay(200);
    relayOnOff(3);
  }
  else if (digitalRead(SwitchPin4) == LOW) {
    delay(200);
    relayOnOff(4);
  }
}

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // This delay gives the chance to wait for a Serial Monitor without blocking if none is found
  delay(1500);

  // Defined in thingProperties.h
  initProperties();

  // Connect to Arduino IoT Cloud
  ArduinoCloud.begin(ArduinoIoTPreferredConnection);

  setDebugMessageLevel(2);
  ArduinoCloud.printDebugInfo();

  pinMode(RelayPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RelayPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RelayPin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RelayPin4, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(wifiLed, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(SwitchPin1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(SwitchPin2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(SwitchPin3, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(SwitchPin4, INPUT_PULLUP);

  //During Starting all Relays should TURN OFF
  digitalWrite(RelayPin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RelayPin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RelayPin3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RelayPin4, HIGH);

  digitalWrite(wifiLed, HIGH);  //Turn OFF WiFi LED
}

void loop() {
  ArduinoCloud.update();
  
  manual_control(); //Control relays manually

  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    digitalWrite(wifiLed, HIGH); //Turn OFF WiFi LED
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(wifiLed, LOW); //Turn ON WiFi LED
  }
}

void onSwitch1Change() {
  if (switch1 == 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(RelayPin1, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Device1 ON");
    toggleState_1 = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(RelayPin1, LOW);
    Serial.println("Device1 OFF");
    toggleState_1 = 0;
  }
}

void onSwitch2Change() {
  if (switch2 == 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(RelayPin2, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Device2 ON");
    toggleState_2 = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(RelayPin2, LOW);
    Serial.println("Device2 OFF");
    toggleState_2 = 0;
  }
}

void onSwitch3Change() {
  if (switch3 == 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(RelayPin3, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Device2 ON");
    toggleState_3 = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(RelayPin3, LOW);
    Serial.println("Device3 OFF");
    toggleState_3 = 0;
  }
}

void onSwitch4Change() {
  if (switch4 == 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(RelayPin4, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Device4 ON");
    toggleState_4 = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(RelayPin4, LOW);
    Serial.println("Device4 OFF");
    toggleState_4 = 0;
  }
}
```

i have included the arduino_secrets and thingproperties in my both pieces of code the difference is that i wanted 8 relay pins to be configured instead of 4 pins
please ask if any thing is needed from me

this was the exact error

```
C:\Users\akki kisu\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoIoTCloud\src\property\Property.cpp:25:19: note: '#pragma message: No RTC available on this architecture - ArduinoIoTCloud will not keep track of local change timestamps .'
   25 |   #pragma message "No RTC available on this architecture - ArduinoIoTCloud will not keep track of local change timestamps ."
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/users/akki kisu/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/10.3.0/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: sketch\Code_NodeMCU_Alexa_ArduinoIotCloud_4Relays.ino.cpp.o:(.text._Z14initPropertiesv+0x1c): undefined reference to `_Z15onSwitch1Changev'
c:/users/akki kisu/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/10.3.0/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: sketch\Code_NodeMCU_Alexa_ArduinoIotCloud_4Relays.ino.cpp.o:(.text._Z14initPropertiesv+0x34): undefined reference to `_Z15onSwitch2Changev'
c:/users/akki kisu/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/10.3.0/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: sketch\Code_NodeMCU_Alexa_ArduinoIotCloud_4Relays.ino.cpp.o:(.text._Z14initPropertiesv+0x40): undefined reference to `_Z15onSwitch3Changev'
c:/users/akki kisu/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/10.3.0/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: sketch\Code_NodeMCU_Alexa_ArduinoIotCloud_4Relays.ino.cpp.o:(.text._Z14initPropertiesv+0x4c): undefined reference to `_Z15onSwitch4Changev'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).
```

Comment: And... *what* is the "error" you got?

Comment: you can reduce the code by almost 90% if you use arrays to hold pin numbers and pin state ... `if (toggleState[relay] == 0) { digitalWrite(RelayPin[relay], HIGH);`

Comment: "Hey please help me with this error. Though I won't tell you what error it is." We are not magical. Please provide the full error output including the line where the error happened

Comment: did you remove the variables in the thing definition on Arduino IoT cloud? or you get error "Undefined reference to onSwitch1Change"?

Comment: What is the difference between your modified code and the original code? Look at it, and you are at least one step nearer to the reason.

Comment: i got an error that error compiling for nodemcu board and for no particular line

Comment: you get linker error "Undefined reference to onSwitch1Change"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Arduino IoT cloud the *variables* synced between the Cloud and the sketch are defined in the definition of the (IoT) *thing*. The *variables* are reflected into the thingProperties.h file which is maintained by the Cloud editor. The on<variable_name> functions in the sketch handle the synchronization of these *variables*. They are declared in the thingProperties.h

You removed the `onSwitchChange` functions, but you didn't remove the switchChange *variables* in the definition of the Thing. The thingProperties.h still contains declarations of `onSwitchChange` functions, but the linker can't find the definition of the function because you removed it from the sketch.

The errors are like this one:

```
undefined reference to `_Z15onSwitch1Changev'
```

To solve this, remove the switchChange *variables* from the *thing* in the Cloud UI.